# Meaning of 说话人最可能 **是** 什么关系？

Tags: grammar

**是**,**有**

Would you please let me know if in this sentence "说话人最可能 **是** 什么关系？", we can use 有 instead of 是 to be read as:

说话人最可能 **有** 什么关系？

Comment: depends on what is it supposed to mean, is there nothing missing from proposed sentence? relation with whom/what? 和什么人／事情,looking at jukuu's samples for either choice would seem very helpful,  e.g.说话人最可能和你是什么关系 could mean "What kin most likely is 说话人 to you", 说话人最可能和你有什么关系？"what has 说话人 most likely got to do with you?

Comment: It's 是, not 有. I keep this a comment as I cannot give further explanation.

Comment: 有, it means that the man is associated with the boss / company / govenment.  说话人最可能 有 什么关系？ = 说话人最可能的  原因是   有 什么 样的 关系？

Comment: Hello Mr. Daniel Yeung .                                                                                              wow.  I got it .  now i understand it better .thanks a lot . thanks a lot . It is a perfect answer .

Comment: I got my perfect answer today. Thanks to all . Thanks to stack exchange. Have a great time .

Comment: Try to translate your sentence into English. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it right to use 是什么关系 rather than 有什么关系?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/34475/when-is-it-right-to-use-%e6%98%af%e4%bb%80%e4%b9%88%e5%85%b3%e7%b3%bb-rather-than-%e6%9c%89%e4%bb%80%e4%b9%88%e5%85%b3%e7%b3%bb)

Comment: You can say both ways. But the former is more common than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

`说话人最可能是什么关系？` means `What is the most possible relation of the speaker?`, implying there is a relationship with only one type of relation.

`说话人最可能有什么关系？` means `What is the most possible relation the speaker has?`, implying there is a relationship but does not imply the exact number of relations.

Comment: This is so far the most precise answer. "是什么关系" implies "which one relation out of the defined few", and "有什么关系" is used when the possibility of relation is undefined many. Both are correct depending on the situation that triggers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Heavily dependent on the context, I guess it means 说话人最可能**(和谁)**是什么关系？ (omitted some words). The 谁 should refer to someone (or something) mentioned right above. Check the context.

Comment: you are right . the total context is a follow :                                                                                           
:女：你准备了几双筷子？男：三双啊。
女：再拿两双，你爷爷奶奶一会儿就过来，我们一起吃。
男：好，妈，碗在哪儿呢？
问：说话人最可能是什么关系？
33．男：我帮您拿行李吧。
女：好的，谢谢你。那个蓝色的是我的。

Comment: 说话人最可能是什么关系？ 是 is correct choice, question asks: what most likely is the relationship  between the two speakers (how are the related)  (see comment #1)

Comment: 是什么关系 and 有什么关系 are both possible, although for kinship 是 may be preferred

Comment: @user17776, in this case 说话人 refers to two persons. 说话人最可能是什么关系？ here, the question asker is checking the relationship between that woman and man. So, there is not any omission here. you can refer to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

是 (is, are), 有 (has, have)

说话人最可能 **是** 什么关系？ What **is** the most likely relationship between the people in the conversation?

说话人最可能 **有** 什么关系？ What the most likely relationship the people in the conversation **have**?

Note, both sentences are vague in the second subject - person or thing, and quantity of the second subject.

Without indicate the number, 说话人 is a singular noun (the speaker), so his relationship (关系) can't be associated with another person, but a thing, however, the "thing" is missing in both sentences. If the "thing" is the second subject, then the sentences should be:

- 说话人**和這件事**最可能**是**什么关系？ What **is** the involvement of the speaker in this event?
- 说话人**和這件事**最可能**有**什么关系？ What involvement the speaker **has** with this event?

If the "persons" are the second subject, then the sentences should be:

**那些(兩個)**在说话的人最可能 **是** 什么关系？

**那些(兩個)**在说话的人最可能 **有** 什么关系？

The English translations are the same as explained in the beginning but added the number of the second subject for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

是/有 can work in the sentence. 是 might sound a little bit better here.

In the "说话人最可能 是/有 什么关系？", '说话人' could be more than one person, maybe two or three. So, the questioner might want to check the relationship among these speakers (说话人s).