# When is it right to use 是什么关系 rather than 有什么关系?

Tags: grammar

> 图中的男人跟男孩儿可能是什么关系？

When to use 是什么关系 or 有什么关系?

Will it be right to use the later in the above phrase?

Answer (score 3):

**是**什么关系 = what **is** the relationship / connection

**有**什么关系 = **have** what relationship / connection

Both are grammatically correct, but in different context, "有什么关系" could mean " what does it matter" e.g. "他死了有什么关系?" = (what does it matter that he died)

- A and B 是 XX 关系 =  the relationship between A and B is of XX
- A and B 有 XX 关系 = A and B have the relationship of XX
- Y 有什么关系 = what does Y matter
- Y 没 关系 = Y doesn't matter
- Y 没什么关系 = Y doesn't matter whatsoever

Example:

"A 和 B **是** 父子的关系" (The relationship between A and B **is** of father and son)

"A 和 B **有** 父子 关系" (A and B **have** the relationship of father and son)

"你输了**有什么关系**?" (**What does it matters** that you lost?)

"你输了**没关系**" (**it doesn't matter** that you lost)

"你输了**没什么关系**" (**it doesn't matter whatsoever** that you lost)

Comment: Thanks very much. Now. Is clear.